# UMBRACO: How to add image on template

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

So, I'm currently new to Umbraco and I'm following some tutorial videos on umbraco.tv. I have created my template and is currently using it to setup the Home Page for my website. I have all the front end working and its displaying properly.

My problem is on the images. I'm using a lot of images for my website and I'm trying to link it to content so the images can be easily changed(not sure if I'm making sense).

[Navigation bar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/od2Mr.png)

If you click the link above, that's how my current navigation bar look like. I want to be able to change the LOGO using Umbraco's media picker. However, everytime I do so, it either gives me the alt name or a runtime error.

This is the code for the image on the template.

```
<img src="@Umbraco.Field("navigationLogo")" height="100" width="50" alt="Logo">
```

I'd appreciate it if you can help me. I'm not sure if I've explained it properly so feel free to ask in detail. Thanks!

Edit -----

I am only coding on browser since it doesn't allow me to login to pull the codes locally (only on trial version since I'm just testing out if its a good CMS).

Not sure if I'm doing it correctly so I apologize. I wrote my code like this

```
@{
   var navigationLogo = @Umbraco.AssignedContent.Site().GetPropertyValue("navigationLogo");
   var navigationLogoMediaItem = @Umbraco.TypedMedia(navigationLogo);

   <img src="@navigationLogoMediaItem.Url" height="100" width="50" alt="Logo" />
 }
```

It's giving me the following error so far.

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'Umbraco.Web.UmbracoHelper' does not contain a definition for 'AssignedContent' and no extension method 'AssignedContent' accepting a first argument of type 'Umbraco.Web.UmbracoHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: You forgot the code

Comment: @Eyescream added the code for the image

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    Layout = "WebBase.cshtml";
    string navigationLogoMediaItem = "";
    if (Model.Content.HasValue("navigationLogo"))
    {
     navigationLogoMediaItem = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<IPublishedContent>("navigationLogo").Url;

    }
}

<img src="@navigationLogoMediaItem" height="100" width="50" alt="Logo" />
```

you can try this

[image: Answer]

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make a few assumptions so please bear with me here.

Assumption 1) On your home node (assuming a document type of 'home") you have a property on it called "navigationLogo".
Assumption 2) This is a media picker data type
Assumption 3) You are using Umbraco 7.6 or newer.
Assumption 4) You aren't using Models Builder

So, assumptions in place there are a few steps you need to go through.

1) Get the navigation logo where ever you are in the site.

```
var navigationLogo = @Umbraco.AssignedContent.Site().GetPropertyValue("navigationLogo");
```

2) next, you'll need to get the media item as I belive you will only have a UDI at this stage.

```
var navigationLogoMediaItem = @Umbraco.TypedMedia(navigationLogo);
```

3) You'll want to put a null check in at this point but to get the url of the logo you simple need to do this:

```
<img src="@navigationLogoMediaItem.Url" height="100" width="50" alt="Logo" />
```

That should get you what you are after. :-)

Comment: If you are assuming Umbraco 7.6, you are using core value converters so @Umbraco.AssignedContent.Site().GetPropertyValue("navigationLogo"); is returning IPublishedContent: .GetPropertyValue<IPublishedContent>("navigationLogo")

Comment: I've tried what you said @Phoenyx I'm not sure if I did it correctly tho. I edited my post above

Comment: What error are you getting? Try with @navigationLogo.Url

Comment: I tried @navigationLogo.Url but still gave me an error

Comment: @BonalizaGarcia sorry there was a mistake in my code, it should be `@Umbraco.AssignedContentItem` not `@Umbraco.AssignedContent`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try out this code.

[memberImage is your document type field name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctA7M.png)

```
@{
    var image = Umbraco.TypedMedia(@Umbraco.Field("memberImage").ToString());
    <img src="@image.Url" style="max-width:250px">
}
```